# Translated Selten Subgame Perfect Eqm Paper

Tags: reference-request

Does anyone know where I can get a translated copy of Selten's original work on subgame perfection?

Comment: Which original work, and which language?

Comment: Are you looking for a translation of Spieltheoretische Behandlung eines Oligopolmodells mit Nachfrageträgheit?

Comment: Yes, this is what I was originally wanting. Ha

Comment: The list of Selten's publications in his [selected works](https://www.e-elgar.com/shop/game-theory-and-economic-behaviour) mentions no translation, so I'd guess none exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this article?

Selten, R. [Reexamination of the perfectness concept for equilibrium points in extensive games](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01766400), Int J Game Theory (1975) 4: 25.

Comment: Yes this is perfect. Do we not have a translation for his 1965 work on demand inertia or is it simply gated?

Comment: The 1975 paper was written in English, the 1965 paper, which introduced SPE, was not. The 1975 paper introduced trembling hands perfection. I can at least assure anyone that nobody but historians of game theory have a need for the 1965 paper.

Comment: Appreciate the response. Make sense!

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Thank you for the additional info!